# Humanizer Months, Weeks, Days, Hours

Tags: c#, humanizer

In C# I am using Humanizer and need to know how many Months, Weeks, Days and Hours are in a TimeSpan in a decreasing amount. Basically the duration of the timespan in decreasing units.

For example:

```
 var z = myTimeSpan.Humanize(???);

 I would like z would be "3 Months, 2 Weeks, 3 Days, 4 Hours"
```

Comment: The source code is [here](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer/blob/master/src/Humanizer/TimeSpanHumanizeExtensions.cs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be possible to make Humanizer display months *and* weeks. Based on the source code that @RufusL linked, [this seems to be intentional](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer/blob/master/src/Humanizer/TimeSpanHumanizeExtensions.cs#L140-L147).

You could do get months, days, and hours, like so:

```
new TimeSpan(109, 4, 0, 0, 0).Humanize(3, maxUnit: TimeUnit.Month)
// 3 months, 17 days, 4 hours
```

Or you could do some post-processing with regex (it's kludgey, and doesn't work for other locales, so I can't fully recommend the approach):

```
var z = new TimeSpan(109, 4, 0, 0, 0).Humanize(3, maxUnit: TimeUnit.Month);
z = Regex.Replace(
    z,
    @"(\d+) days?",
    m => TimeSpan.FromDays(int.Parse(m.Groups[1].ToString())).Humanize(2)
);
// 3 months, 2 weeks, 3 days, 4 hours
```

Comment: This can also be found here: https://humanizr.net/#humanize-timespan